How to resolve "ambiguous column" error in Laravel Livewire PowerGrid filter with joined tables?
I'm using Laravel Livewire with PowerGrid v2.x and have a query that joins multiple tables to display transaction data. Both transactions and invoices tables contain a transaction_type column, which can either be buy or sell. I want to use a dropdown filter on transaction_type in the PowerGrid column, but I encounter an "ambiguous column" error when searching by this field.
Here's the relevant code:
Transaction::query()
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'transactions.user_id')
->leftJoin('invoices', 'invoices.id', '=', 'transactions.invoice_id')
->leftJoin('chainalysis_risk_assessments', 'chainalysis_risk_assessments.transaction_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
->select([
    'transactions.*',
    'users.email',
    'users.phone_number',
    'chainalysis_risk_assessments.category',
    'chainalysis_risk_assessments.cluster_name',
    'chainalysis_risk_assessments.risk',
    'chainalysis_risk_assessments.risk_reason',
    'chainalysis_risk_assessments.data',
]);

Here's the PowerGrid column definition:
Column::add()
->title('Type')
->field('transaction_type', 'transactions.transaction_type')
->sortable()
->searchable()
->makeInputSelect(collect([
    ['transaction_type' => "buy", "title" => "Buy"],
    ['transaction_type' => "sell", "title" => "Sell"]
]), 'title', 'transaction_type');

If I prefix the column with transactions.transaction_type, the dropdown filter displays correctly but doesn't retain its value when applied; it clears out instead. If I remove the prefix, I get an ambiguous column error.
I've tried using column aliases and other workarounds, but nothing has worked so far. Is there a way to ensure that the filter retains its value while avoiding the ambiguous column error?

This usually happens when you do a join but you do it on a column that is the same name in both databases so its confused as to which one you are talking about.  Such as db A, and db B both having an id column, you cant just say id you need to be specific such as a.id or b.id , if that makes sense, review your code and find the issue.  That being said, your question looks good so I'm going to submit it to be allowed as a question.

"same name in both databases" - I think you mean same column name in both tables

Yeah I should of been more specific, he is correct.  The proper format is dbo.tablename for the record.

The issue is from the transaction_type column being present in both the transactions and invoices tables, which causes the ambiguous column error in SQL
Step1: To avoid ambiguity, alias the transaction_type column in the query
Transaction::query()
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'transactions.user_id')
    ->leftJoin('invoices', 'invoices.id', '=', 'transactions.invoice_id')
    ->leftJoin('chainalysis_risk_assessments', 'chainalysis_risk_assessments.transaction_id', '=', 'transactions.id')
    ->select([
        'transactions.*',
        'users.email',
        'users.phone_number',
        'chainalysis_risk_assessments.category',
        'chainalysis_risk_assessments.cluster_name',
        'chainalysis_risk_assessments.risk',
        'chainalysis_risk_assessments.risk_reason',
        'chainalysis_risk_assessments.data',
        'transactions.transaction_type as transaction_transaction_type', // Alias this column
    ]);

This ensures that the transaction_type from the transactions table is uniquely identified as transaction_transaction_type.
step2: Update the PowerGrid column definition to reference the aliased field:
Column::add()
    ->title('Type')
    ->field('transaction_transaction_type', 'transactions.transaction_type') // Use alias
    ->sortable()
    ->searchable()
    ->makeInputSelect(collect([
        ['transaction_transaction_type' => "buy", "title" => "Buy"],
        ['transaction_transaction_type' => "sell", "title" => "Sell"]
    ]), 'title', 'transaction_transaction_type');

step3: PowerGrid may need an explicit reference to the aliased column for the filter to work correctly. You can customize the filter logic in PowerGrid’s configuration:
->makeInputSelect(
    collect([
        ['transaction_transaction_type' => "buy", "title" => "Buy"],
        ['transaction_transaction_type' => "sell", "title" => "Sell"]
    ]),
    'title',
    'transaction_transaction_type' // Reference the aliased column
)
->filter(function ($builder, $value) {
    $builder->where('transactions.transaction_type', $value);
});

This tells PowerGrid to filter the transactions.transaction_type column when applying the dropdown filter.

Unfortunately not resolved. When I used the above approach. it started adding query to the alias column i.e. transactions.transaction_transaction_type. And this column will never exist
